# Insert nested JSON to MySQL using Node

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js

I am using Node to INSERT JSON to MySQL, using Node.js

This works fine, until I have nested values.

**Example of my JSON is here:**

```
var result2 = [{
"id": 89304,
"employeeDetails": {
    "id": 102524,
    "version": 9
}
}, {
"id": 89305,
"employeeDetails": {
    "id": 102522,
    "version": 99
}
}];
```

***Note:*** I am using the above for testing, as further on I want to call API requests in JSON and return them.

**This is how I am sending it to MySQL using Node.js:**

```
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO employees SET ?', result2,
function(error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
});
```

Without nesting, this is working fine, however the nested employeeDetails gives me the following error:

```
Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'employeeDetails' in 'field list'
```

My current table format is:

- Field: "userID", INT
- Field: "id", INT
- Field: "version", INT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the doc https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values :

> Objects are turned into key = 'val' pairs for each enumerable property
>   on the object. If the property's value is a function, it is skipped;
>   if the property's value is an object, toString() is called on it and
>   the returned value is used.

So you can't use nested objects because it's considered as a field.

You would instead do a loop through your array of objects :

```
var result2 = [{
  "id": 89304,
  "userId": 102524,
  "version": 9
}, {
  "id": 89305,
  "userId": 102522,
  "version": 99
}
}];
for(var i in result2) {
  var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO employees SET ?', result2[i],
  function(error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
  });
}
```

Or more simply, if your goal is to accomplish a bulk INSERT, using nested arrays :

```
var result2 = [[89304, 102524, 9], [89305, 102522, 99]];
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO employees(id, userId, version) VALUES ?', [result2],
function(error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
});
```

There a method to convert from your original nested objects to Bulk INSERT :

```
var result2 = result2.map(function(el){
    return [el.id, el.employeeDetails.id, el.employeeDetails.version];
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I am retrieving the JSON via an API call. So to get rid of the nested objects, I would need to use firstly json.parse to convert my JSON?

Comment: You're welcome ;) Actually if your API already send JSON, JSON.parse is useless. What you need to do is either changing the id of the employeeDetails object to userId so there is no conflict with the first one and then plain it or iterate through the array and objects to go with Bulk INSERT

Comment: Thanks! I guess what I'm confused with is getting the JSON object from my original nested type to -  **var result2 = [[89304, 102524, 9], [89305, 102522, 99]];**

Comment: I added a way to convert your original array ;)

Comment: Life saver! Thank you do much!